# Ajax,Privat24-api: ошибка invalid signature

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Отсылаю  ajax запрос на https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/balance(). Данное api принимает xml документ. В ответе получаю invalid signature.

> Выкладка из Privatbank docs:
>
> Сигнатура запроса рассчитывется следующим образом
>   (PHP):$sign=sha1(md5($data.$password)); $data - содержимое тега 
>   данного запроса; $password - личный пароль мерчанта
>
> Ссылка на документацию:https://api.privatbank.ua/balance.html

Как именно нужно отформатировать содержимое тега data?

Вычисление сигнатуры:

```
$pass="***************";
    $data="<oper>cmt</oper><wait>0</wait><test>0</test><payment><prop name=\"cardnum\" value=\"*************\"></prop><prop name=\"country\" value=\"UA\"></prop></payment>";
    $sign =sha1(md5($data.$pass));
```

и сам код Ajax запроса:

```
var xml = '' +
    '<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>'+
    '<request version="1.0">'+
      '<merchant>'+
        '<id>mercaht-id</id>'+
        '<signature>'+'<?$sign?>'+'</signature>'+
     '</merchant>'+
      '<data>'+
        '<oper>cmt</oper>'+
        '<wait>0</wait>'+
        '<test>0</test>'+
        '<payment id="">'+
         ' <prop name="cardnum" value="cart-number" />'+
         ' <prop name="country" value="UA" />'+
        '</payment>'+
      '</data>'+
    '</request>';
        function Privat24Info(){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/balance", false);
            request.send(xml);
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
```

Comment: В приведенном коде содержимое переменной `$data` и тега `<data>` в переменной `xml` отличаются. Как минимум, наличием пробелов перед тегами `<prop>`.

Comment: @Yaant Я понимаю, пробывал самые различные варианты. Invalid signature в любом случае

Comment: Варианты тут пробовать не надо. Надо просто убедиться, что содержимое вашей `$data` и соответствующей подстроки в `xml` совпадают с точностью до байта. Из вопроса в нынешнем его виде это ни капли не очевидно..

Comment: @Yaant сейчас попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Yaant решил проблему, дело было в несовпадении

Answer (score 0):

```
$pass = 'GURY0F2GRfK84vANld3lno13jSw1v66L';

$data  = '<oper>cmt</oper>';
$data .= '<wait>0</wait>';
$data .= '<test>0</test>';
$data .= '<payment id="">';
$data .= '<prop name="sd" value="01.10.2016" />';
$data .= '<prop name="ed" value="30.10.2016" />';
$data .= '<prop name="card" value="'.$card.'" />';
$data .= '</payment>';


$sign = sha1(md5($data.$pass));
```

Вот, етот код у меня работает

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю здесь проблема совсем не в данных, а в способе передачи.
Вы используете Ajax, а это уже получается кроссдоменный запрос, который может быть запрещен на стороне privat24.
Рекомендую реализовывать это при помощи curl или что-то в этом роде.
[Пример от привата](https://link.privatbank.ua/console/wiki/client_auth)

Хотя в коде у вас я нашел ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может быть причина в ней...